# What could cause a second no funtional mouse pointer to appear on my gnome desktop?

Tags: gnome, mouse, mouse-pointer

I just started to see this problem this morning. My mouse works just fine but I'm seeing a second stationary pointer on the desktop and it's very annoying. I've tried rebooting but it just reappears.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a dual boot Acer Aspire 5. I just started seeing this issue this morning.
I'd really appreciate some insight into this issue

Answer (score 1):

Problem is resolved.
I went into display settings and turned off "fractional scaling" and all is well.
I remembered that I had turned that on yesterday and thought it was worth a try.

Carson

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using Wayland or Xorg?